# Python: How can I fetch data from SQL for a ttk combobox based on the selection of another combobox

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter, combobox

I am trying to have two ttk comboboxes that fetch data from a sqlite database. I managed to be able and list items in one combobox named divisiondropmenu using the combo_division() function. Now I am trying to do a similar thing for the second combobox named productdropmenu, but the list would need to be narrowed down based on the first selected item in combobox named divisiondropmenu.

For the SQL query to pass the needed information for the second combobox I was thinking of something of this sort:

```
'SELECT * FROM productname WHERE divisionname=?', (function_name())
```

Code for the two comboboxes so far:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.ttk import *
import sqlite3


def combo_division():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('anglingdatabase.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT divisionname FROM productdivision')
    data = []
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
    data.append(row[0])
    return data

root = Tk()
root.title("Random Window Title")
root.geometry('1280x720')

rows = 0
while rows < 50:
    root.rowconfigure(rows, weight=1)
    root.columnconfigure(rows, weight=1)
    rows += 1


divisiondropmenu = ttk.Combobox(root)
divisiondropmenu['values'] = combo_division()
divisiondropmenu.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', selecteddivision)
divisiondropmenu.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky='NESW')

productdropmenu = ttk.Combobox(root)
productdropmenu['values'] = combo_product()
productdropmenu.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky='NESW')

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = combo_division()
example_sql = ''' SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE division in ('{}') '''.format("','".join(data))
```

You could build the actual SQL dynamically provided that the data was never user input (to avoid SQL injection).

Comment: Thank you, this is very useful for my SQL query construct. I am still looking for a way how to obtain and be able to use the item selected in the first combobox that will determine the choices in the second combobox.

Comment: So you would want to have an ajax call back to an API of your app (or use a websocket), have a javascript event send the data from the first box, and then populate the second list with the results, and then make that visible to the user on the screen.

Comment: Not ajax. All information is stored locally in a sqlite database. Combobox1 fetches information from one table and combobox2 fetches it from a different table. The relation is that combobox2 depends on the selection made in combobox1.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I need to do something similar.

Comment: @MelanieLauzon No, I have not.